# In Gridview, I want to capture the Column Id's value for the selected Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In Gridview, I want to capture the Column Id's value for the selected row. When I click "Select" and Click "Go" button, I receive this output:

> Captured: MainContent_GridView1

How do I select the ID of that particular row?

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

        String RowID = row.ClientID;


        Response.Write("Captured: " + RowID);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:"+ ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the control ID, as found in the HTML output (e.g. `btnGo`)? I don't think that the individual rows of the GridView have one. At least, I don't see any in the page source view of the browser.

Comment: I have Id, Name, Address, Phone, Email, Source, Message, Date and I want to retrieve the Id value of selected Row .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get the field values in a row is to add the field names to the `DataKeyNames` of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id,Phone" ... >
```

In code-behind, you can get the values this way:

```
int Id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"];
string phone = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Phone"];
```

I included `Phone` in the list to show that several fields can be specified. In your case, `DataKeyNames` would only contain `Id`.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer if it solves your problem (using the check mark).

Comment: Now, a quick one, How do I use this 'Id' to insert into another datatable?

Comment: You would have to write an `INSERT` query and set one of the parameters to that value. You may find some help about those queries on the Web.

Comment: string insertQuery = "insert into NeedToQuote (Name, Address, Phone, Email, Source, Message ) SELECT Name, Address, Phone, Email, Source, Message From Enquiry WHERE Id= ' " + RowId+" ' ";

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean, you have a GridView that is showing the id in one of the columns. So, if it was the first column, you could do something like

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
string id = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: When I followed your code, my result was blank as in 

        'Captured: '

I want to obtain the value of ID for that particular Row to use it for data insertion.

Comment: @Anoj Interesting, what are the columns on your GridView (in order)?

Comment: I have Id, Name, Address, Phone, Email, Source, Message, Date.

Comment: @Anoj Are you still getting 'Captured: ' when you are using Response.Write("Captured: " + row.Cells[0].Text);

Comment: The problem was solved using 
int Id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"];
string phone = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Phone"];

Answer (score 0):

```
String Id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text
```