# ASP.net gridview get text from selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net

i tried to get a text from gridview cell (which bound by database) `string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;`
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which means `.Cells[1]` is Null

Comment: is there a control in the cell? if yes, then you should get the value from the control in the cell.

Comment: If you want to retrieve a value that is already stored in the data source, you can use `DataKeyNames` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637237/in-gridview-i-want-to-capture-the-column-ids-value-for-the-selected-row/36637636#36637636).